# Calendar UI widget for wscript/vbscript

Tags: windows, vbscript, wsh

I'm a newbie to windows scripting. Is there a Calendar UI widget which I can use from wsh to get user input? I basically need to get a Date from the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBScript only has the [`InputBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yfdhzk5.aspx) function for the user input: you can use it to prompt the user for a date string in whatever date format is supported by their locale ("8/10/2009", "8/10/09", "August 10, 2009", "Aug 10, 2009" etc) and then convert it to a Date variant using the [`DateValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we249285.aspx) function.

If you need, you probably want an [HTML Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536471.aspx). Check out Microsoft TechNet Script Center for [info and tips on HTAs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742317.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>calendar</title>
    <hta:application
         scroll="no"
         singleinstance="no"
         windowstate="normal"
    >
</head>
<script type="text/vbscript">
    Sub cal1_click()
        ddate.value=cal1.value 
        div1.style.visibility="hidden"
    End Sub
</script>
<body>
<div>
<input id="ddate" type="text" value="click here" onclick="div1.style.visibility='visible'">
<div id="div1" style="visibility:hidden;">
    <object id="cal1" 
            classid="clsid:8E27C92B-1264-101C-8A2F-040224009C02">
    </object>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```